# XSS payload without html tags

Tags: web-application, xss, appsec

Which payload can be used to exploit XSS without using html tags <>. These tags are filtered(sanitized) and encoded in output.

Comment: What's your injection context?

Comment: @Arminius It is .net app which blocks xss using <> and generates an potentially dangerous error for this.

Comment: Have you tried encode or even double encode your input? Encode might work if the application does not use ".NET AntiXSS Library" ( https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library )

Comment: I think @Arminius meant where your injection is interpreted, for example, if your injection is part of JavaScript code or inside of a HTML event (onclik, onload, etc), you don't need to use HTML tags, you could inject JS code directly.

Comment: you can't; you need an HTML context to perform XSS and you don't have HTML.

Answer (score 3):

This might not prove successful but perhaps you can try something like the following as it does not use the specific tags (<>) you are referring to:

````
Set.constructor`alert\x28document.domain\x29```
````

This was found from the below OWASP source for attempting XSS by filter evasion techniques

Source:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet